# parsing and matching weird structure of html using python

Tags: python, html, parsing, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

First, I want to parse this html:

```
<body>
    <div id="contents">
        <div id="links">
            <a href='url1'>link-1</a></div>
        <div id="info">
            <p>apple</p></div>
        <div id="links">
            <a href='url2'>link-2</a>
            <a href='url3'>link-3</a></div>
        <div id="info">
            <p>bear</p></div>
        <div id="links">
            <a href='url4'>link-4</a></div>
        <div id="info">
            <p>cat</p></div>
        <div id="links">
            <a href='url5'>link-5</a>
            <a href='url6'>link-6</a>
            <a href='url7'>link-7</a></div>
        <div id="info">
            <p>duck</p></div>
        <div id="links">
            <a href='url8'>link-8</a></div>
        <div id="info">
            <p>egg</p></div>
        #etc
    </div>
</body>
```

Here my purpose is to "grab all link and info, and matching them". But, there are 8 links and 5 infos, so it doesn't match clearly.

```
def link_collect(soup):
    tempaddress = []
    link_list = [0]*10
    d = 0
    linksearch = soup.findAll("a")
    for r in linksearch:
        try:
            if "url" in r['href']:
                tempaddress.append(r['href']
        except:
            a=0
    for clearing in tempaddress:
        cleared = urlparse(str(clearing))
        clink = cleared.scheme + "://" + cleared.netloc + cleared.path
        link_list[d] = clink
        d = d+1
    link_list = delete_zero(link_list)
    return link_list

def info_collect(soup)
    tempinfo = soup.find_all(id="info")
    info_list = [0]*10
    d=0
    for r in tempinfo:
        infodata = r.get_text()
        info_list[d] = infodata
        d=d+1
    info_list = delete_zero(info_list)
    return info_list

targetpage = "http://address"
opening = urlopen(targetpage)
soup = BeautifulSoup(opening.read())
link = link_collect(soup)
info = info_collect(soup)
for n in range(0, len(info)):
    print(str(link[n]) + " = " + str(info[n]))
```

And when run, the result came like:

```
url1 = apple
url2 = bear
url3 = cat
url4 = duck
url5 = egg
```

> ```
> Error : url 6, 7, 8 can't match
> ```

But, I want result like this:

```
url1 = apple
url2 = bear
url3 = bear
url4 = cat
url5 = duck
etc
```

How can I make like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get your `a` element parent which are `div` using the [**`find_all()`**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all) method. Next use the [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function to iterate over pair `(div, info)` and again the `find_all()` method to get all link for each `div`.

```
In [85]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [86]: soup = BeautifulSoup("""<body>
    <div id="contents">
        <div id="links">
            <a href='url1'>link-1</a></div>
        <div id="info">
            <p>apple</p></div>
        <div id="links">
            <a href='url2'>link-2</a>
            <a href='url3'>link-3</a></div>
        <div id="info">
            <p>bear</p></div>
        <div id="links">
            <a href='url4'>link-4</a></div>
        <div id="info">
            <p>cat</p></div>
        <div id="links">
            <a href='url5'>link-5</a>
            <a href='url6'>link-6</a>
            <a href='url7'>link-7</a></div>
        <div id="info">
            <p>duck</p></div>
        <div id="links">
            <a href='url8'>link-8</a></div>
        <div id="info">
            <p>egg</p></div>
        #etc
    </div>
</body>""")

In [87]: links = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': 'links'})

In [88]: infos = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'id': 'info'})

In [157]: for lk, inf in zip(links, infos):
   .....:     for tag in lk.find_all('a'):
   .....:         print(inf.text, tag.attrs['href'])
   .....:         

apple url1

bear url2

bear url3

cat url4

duck url5

duck url6

duck url7

egg url8
```

Comment: thank you michael, and i ran this code a moment ago, so in my case, i'm not use IDLE, anyway I print (d) at line 91, and I give just {'apple'}, only one. and one more thing, i don't wanna take "link-n", what i want is "urls", how to extract that?

Comment: thank you more, and I have another problem, now when I run, I see Error on print(inf.text, tag.attrs['href']), keyerror : 'href'

Comment: @HyungsooKim please try again. It should work by now